# Make a short table of contents followed by a detailed table of contents when using the book class

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using the [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book?lang=en) class for my thesis. I would like to create a short table of contents (containing only chapter titles), followed by a detailed table of contents (containing the default table of contents information, i.e., chapter, section, and subsection titles).

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247558/15622) is a nice example. However, it is for the [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en) class. How can I adapt the example for the [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book?lang=en) class?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First ch}
\section{First sec ch 1}
\subsection{Sub A}
\subsection{Sub B}
\section{Second sec ch 1}

\chapter{Second ch}
\section{First sec ch 2}
\subsection{Sub A}
\subsection{Sub B}
\section{Second sec ch 2}

\chapter{Third ch}
\section{First sec ch 3}
\subsection{Sub A}
\subsection{Sub B}
\section{Second sec ch 3}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the `etoc` package, you can achieve the following:

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{chapter}
\tableofcontents

\etocignoretoctocdepth
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Congrats on passing the 40k reputation mark!!